# URL Rewrite HTACCESS with parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do what seems like a simple redirect. But, I'm running into an issue. I'm entering the below code into the .htaccess file.

This redirect works (example.com/?p=2011 -> example.com)

```
# Redirect 301 /?p=2011 /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=2011$
RewriteRule (.*) /? [R=301,L]
```

I can't get this one to work (example.com/publications?page=3 -> example.com/resources/). I can't seem to figure out why. This is what I tried below.

```
# Redirect 301 /publications?page=3 /resources/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/publications$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=3$
RewriteRule (.*) /resources/? [R=301,L]
```

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Is `/publications` an existent directory?

Comment: It is not. It's a wordpress site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is running into this issue on a Wordpress website I found a solution. I wasn't able to figure out how to redirect it through the .htaccess file.

I was able to create the redirects with the plugin "Redirections".

Hope this helps someone